# getting strange emails trough contact form

Tags: php, contact-form

Hello I have a custom simple contact form where users can send emails, I get a email when this contact form is used.

But now i got like 400 mails in 1 hour from 3 contact forms from my website. And the mails contain strange data I have attached a image showing the emails i got[image: strange chars]

i also got mails with things like `\\\\\\\' oR \\\\\\%\\\\\'=\\\\\\2` in it or stuf like 2=7 etc...

what is this ?

Comment: Check the logs to see the serder ip and look for a pattern

Comment: Maybe anti-spam techniques should help.

Comment: You really should add some form validation so crap like this doesn't get through.

Comment: it's just a spam attack, you will have to add captcha to stop this abuse.

Comment: or any javascript "toys".

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not spam issues.


Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you expose a form over the web, it is going to be found by bots. The bots will dump rubbish into your form and see if they can post it. Sometimes it is just garbage and other times it will contain links or other spam.

Most basic bots can be defeated by having a form element that fails validation if anything is entered - as bots normally put garbage in all fields. In your case, you could discard forms that don't contain a valid email address and it would solve quite a lot of the problem.

You *could* add a Captcha / Recaptcha - but they are a real problem for humans using your form - so think carefully before you go down this route.

The most reliable and hassle free way to go is normally to ask people to create a basic account with your website. That way, if they start spamming you, you can hell-ban them (i.e. make them think they can still submit the form, but discard it from spam user accounts).

The spam problem won't simply go away if you defeat the bots - as search-engine-optimisation consultants are happy to hand-crank entries thinking you'll then hand them money for their dodgy servies.

Comment: There is a slight issue with that one - it adds the required text in plain text in the browser, so bots can easily read that one.

Comment: thank you i will fix it,, maybe use GD and create some image!

Comment: If you really want to use a Captcha, the ReCaptcha service is quite robust - and helps to digitise books! http://www.google.com/recaptcha